# What happens when a React app, which contains Flow annotations, is launched?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, transpiler

I'm relatively new to web development. I have a react app which makes use of the usual JSX components. These get compiled to regular html and JavaScript, presumably by a react script created when I first ran `create-react-app MyApp`.

My package.json file contains the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    ...
}
```

and I run `npm start` to launch the app.

I have recently been exploring the [flow](https://flow.org/en/) static analysis tool, as this seems to be gaining ground over the older [React PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) in the React community. I have seen StackOverflow questions alluding to the fact that JavaScript code with Flow annotations is no longer valid JavaScript and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43838589/201113) that say in order to use such JavaScript it needs to be transpiled to remove the Flow annotations. The Flow website lists `Babel` and `flow-remove-types` as two transpile tools.

My confusion is, my project works fine without me explicitly transpiling the code. E.g. the following JavaScript and Flow code in `MyApp/src/index.js`:

```
const someSillyConst: any = this;
console.log(`test: ${someSillyConst}`);
```

Becomes this:

```
var someSillyConst = this;
console.log('test: ' + someSillyConst);
```

when I examine a file called `static/js/bundle.js` in Chrome's dev tools.

Yet I can still view the original version in `Users/barry/MyApp/src/index.js`, again in Chrome's dev tools.

So, what is happening between me running `npm start` and the app rendering in Chrome that removes non-valid JavaScript, in this case Flow annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it works is – create-react-app supports flow out of the box since it's using **babel-preset-react** which in turn includes **babel-flow**.

So, your code actually gets transpiled. The transpilation in your case also converts the template literal to plain old string concatenation (and the `const` to `var`).

preset-react: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/
babel-preset-react-app: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-react-app/index.js

If you want to explore all the config stuff which is hidden by create react app, you may use `npm eject` – although you probably want to do this for another project since this is a one way operation. This command is going to copy over all the config files for you to edit.

Comment: And is it webpack that creates the bundle.js file?

Comment: Yes, you can find the prod config here: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js

Comment: If I may ask - is it hard for you to grasp what create-react-app actually does? I'm not sure whether there's a write up such as "it does this with that and that with this" and i think this would prove valuable to people who are just starting out with this whole js build/toolchain

Comment: A write up would be very useful, but would probably go out of date very quickly! :)